# What kind of JavaScript is this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I have an application that has this format scattered around but I dont know what kind it is. It's not jQuery, so what is it?

```
$('some_edit').style.display  = "block";
$('some_views').style.display = "none";
```

I get this in firebug and I know the element is present:

```
$("some_edit").style is undefined
```

Comment: I'd say there's a good chance it is prototypejs. That's how you get elements by ID. http://jsfiddle.net/Ntwwz/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A lot of people have defined the '$' symbol as a substitute for document.getElementById().

Basically:

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
$("ElementID").innerHTML = "Text"; //Usage
```

A more proper, "namespace" example:

```
var DOM = { // creating the namespace "DOM"
    $: (function() {
        if(document.getElementById)
            return function(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
        else if(document.all)
            return function(id) { return document.all[id]; }
        else
            return function(id) { /* I don't even want to get into document.layers */ }
    })()
};

// Later in the code:
{
    function ExampleFunction() {
        // ...
        DOM.$("ElementID").style.backgroundColor = "#96d0a0"; // a nice minty green color
        // ...
    }
}
```

I have used a [self-invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720283/what-is-this-practice-called-in-javascript) pattern (`function(){ ... }()`) in this example.

Comment: This is most likely the situation.

Comment: Neat idea... I don't do a lot of JavaScript, but I might just use this little shortcut next time around. +1

Comment: lol. please don't. thinking like that from everyone that ever did any js release is what causes framework compatibility issues these days. namespace!

Comment: For complete answer, provide the namespace option for folks :)

Answer (score 16):

It could be many things - examine the source code (or use Firebug) and see what JS libraries are being loaded.

Comment: If you're going to use Firebug, may as well set a breakpoint and step into it just to be doubly sure which library is being executed.

Answer (score 4):

at first i thought the jquery selector would likely have been `$("#some_edit")` and then `.css()`. so I would have said, prototype or mootools or a home brew $.

you can certainly discount both `mootools` and `prototype`, because if the selector returns an object, then the style property will be available (ignoring best practices in both frameworks on setting styles).

this leaves, the site uses homebrew $ assignment or jquery, which is not being used correctly.

actually, $("foo").style.blah in jquery will produce this very exception (even if the selector was good) - here is jsfiddle to the rescue

case point jquery (triggers):
http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/vmsZn/

case point prototype (works):
http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/vmsZn/1/

case point mootools (works):
http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/vmsZn/2/

Answer (score 0):

It is setting the display style for the two page elements - the display property specifies the type of box an element should generate.

block = The element will generate a block box (a line break before and after the element)
none = The element will generate no box at all

Answer (score 0):

Put a [0] in front of $('some_views') to return the Native DOM Element.

$('some_views')[0].style.display = "none";

or $('some_views').get(0).style.display = "none";

or $('some_views').css('display', 'none') to iterate through the collection of DOM elements.

Answer (score -4):

It's JQuery -- uses $ as its key variable.

Added:

Could also be mootools. Also uses $

Added:

'some_edit' would be the id of an element.

ps. I agree $ could be anything. Odds are though that it is JQuery or Mootools. "When you hear hoof beats, think horses, not zebras."

Comment: Many libraries use $ as a helper variable, it's certainly not jQuery specific.

Comment: Not neccessarily - Many libraries uses $, but I will agree that JQuery is the likely library (as it has the most widespread adoption)

Comment: @driis - jQuery uses css type selectors. $('some_edit') is not a valid jquery selector... unless the page has a node called "some_edit". If it were an id it would be "#some_edit". If its a class, then ".some_edit".

Comment: Re @driis. Whoops, me bad. Thanks.