# What does (function (x,y){...})(a,b); mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I saw this function:

```
(function (x, y, data, lbl, dot) {
    // Function body...
})(x, y, data[i], labels[i], dot);
```

What is this? A function? Why place a function definition in `()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the following JavaScript construct called a Closure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872604/is-the-following-javascript-construct-called-a-closure)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In javascript you can have `anonymous` and `self invoking` functions.

```
function add(a, b)
{
   return a + b;
}
```

is same as

```
var add = function (a, b) {
             return a + b;
          }
```

and you call these as

```
add(10, 20)
```

You can define the function and call it immediately as

```
(
   function(a, b)
   {
      return a + b;
   }
)(10, 20);
```

The

```
   (
       function(a, b)
       {
          return a + b;
       }
    )
```

part defines a function, and the `(10, 20)` immediately after it calls the function just defined, with 10 and 20 as arguments to it.

Since the function does not have a name, it cannot be used later in the code.

The code in your question is probably *minified*, and creates a function in a similar way and calls it immediately.

Comment: I dont get it....Why is the function not created like this instead::::::: function () {} (); ....why is it like (function(){})(); it is just anonymous which means no name right...I know it semicolon plays a role here...please explain if you can.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Yes, the difference is the name. `function x{} ();` creates a function `x` and calls it immediately. But it can be called again also, using the name: `x();`. But `(function(){})();` creates an anonymous function, calls it and after that the function cannot be used again.

Comment: Why do I create anonymous function (never use it again) and call it immediately after defining? - Instead I could just (in this example) return 10 + 20. AND not define function to have logic of a + b and later calling it just for 10,20?

Comment: Yeah, I second this. Why arguments in an IIFE? One could just hardcode the values to put in there.

Answer (score 7):

`function() {}` is a [definition of an anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/function_Operator) and `(function() {})()` is a call of that anonymous function.

This works since functions can be passed like data. So `window.alert` is the known `alert` function itself and `window.alert()` will call that function.

This technique is often used to keep the current variable scope clean as the function has its own variable scope.

Comment: +1 for mentioning scope as the reason for using the technique

Comment: `function() {}` raises an error in Chrome: "unexpected '('".

Answer (score 5):

It is a self anonymous invoking function. The function is defined and executed immediately. The parenthesis  that wrap the function ensure that it is treated as a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#The_function_expression_%28function_operator%29) instead of a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#The_function_declaration_%28function_statement%29). The final pair of parenthesis invoke the function and pass the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

A self-executing anonymous function would be a pretty accurate description.

Answer (score 1):

It is a self invoking function, it is executed right away. 
Self invoking functions are effective for avoiding creation of global variables, jQuery uses this very effectively.

Answer (score 0):

The function inside the parenthesis is an anonymous function. I cannot say why this is done the way it is done, but the programmer defines and anonymous function, and calls it immediately. You could probably do the same thing by simply substituting its arguments with the values passed in, and removing the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
var funct = function(x,y) { }
funct(1,2)
```

is the same as

```
(function(x,y){ })(1,2);
```

it defines a self invoking anonymous function. It gets executed and then thrown away. It is a way of tidying your code (although this is a bad example) and having private variables in only that scope. It also won't get stored within the closure.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out that

`!(function (a, b) {`

on poly up the math website makes it so every now and then it stops the click from working