# What does this "(function(){});", a function inside brackets, mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, scope, anonymous-function, javascript-namespaces

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What does this mean? (function (x,y)){…}){a,b); in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921922/what-does-this-mean-function-x-y-a-b-in-javascript)
>   [What do parentheses surrounding a JavaScript object/function/class declaration mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-object-function-class-declaration-me)

Hi All

I don't know what the following does:

```
(function(){
  // Do something here
  ...
})(someWord) //Why is this here?;
```

My questions are:

1. What's the meaning of putting a function inside brackets .i.e. `(function(){});`?
2. What do the set of brackets do at the end of a function?

I usually see these in jquery codes, and some other javascript libraries.

Comment: same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921922/what-does-this-mean-function-x-y-a-b-in-javascript/3921997#3921997

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You're immediately calling an anonymus function with a specific parameter.

An example:

```
(function(name){
  alert(name);
})('peter')
```

This alerts "**peter**".

In the case of jQuery you might pass `jQuery` as a parameter and use `$` in your function. So you can still use jQuery in noConflict-mode but use the handy `$`:

```
jQuery.noConflict()
(function($){
  var obj = $('<div/>', { id: 'someId' });
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, it makes sense now

Comment: Can this function be given a name? or does it have to be anonymous?

Answer (score 12):

You are making a function that is immediately being called, with `someWord` as a parameter.

Comment: Wow, this is the sharpest answer and I get it. thanks

Answer (score 7):

It's a way to define an anonymous function and then immediately executing it -- leaving no trace, as it were. The function's scope is truly local. The `()` brackets at the end execute the function -- the enclosing brackets are to disambiguate what is being executed.

Answer (score 7):

Basically this lets you declare an anonymous function, and then by enclosing it in parentheses and writing `(someWord)` you are running the function. You could think of it as declaring an object and then immediately instantiating the object.

Answer (score 7):

It's used to create anonymous function (function without name that can be "nested" inside other function) and pass argument to that function.
The someWord is passed as argument, and the function can read it using the keyword "arguments".

Simple example of usage:

```
function Foo(myval) {
    (function(){
      // Do something here
      alert(arguments[0]);
    })(myval); //pass myval as argument to anonymous function
}
...
Foo(10);
```