# What (function(){})(); mean?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this “(function(){});”, a function inside brackets, mean in javascript ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043647/what-does-this-function-a-function-inside-brackets-mean-in-javascript)

```
(function(){
    ---this code at here ----
})();
```

What does `(function(){})();` mean? Please explain it to me.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043647/what-does-this-function-a-function-inside-brackets-mean-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is immediately executed after parsing it.

Comment: ok, what is the reason to put it in a function body then, rather than just writeing its code within the script tags?

Answer (score 5):

It makes an anonymous function and executes it. You use it to prevent variables from poluting the global scope.

```
(function(){
  var test = "Hello";
})();

alert(test); //test will be undefined here
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you use a function expression as a closure which gets executed immediately and 'this code at here' will not pollute global namespace.