# jQuery (function(a){...})(jQuery);

Tags: jquery, ajax

I get a *.js file code similar like:

```
(function(a){ 

   a("#div_element").removeClass("show message");
 
   ....

})(jQuery);
```

I'm trying to understand:

1. What is ***(function(a){...})(jQuery);*** ?
2. How to use it?
3. What is ***a*** here? Because I seen normal code looks like:

   `$("#div_element").removeClass("show message");`

Comment: Similar Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464635/what-does-function-jquery-do-mean

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? (function (x,y)){...}){a,b); in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921922/what-does-this-mean-function-x-y-a-b-in-javascript)

Comment: Other similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806150/javascript-function-vs-function, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192227/javascriptwhat-function-mean, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043647/what-does-this-function-a-function-inside-brackets-mean-in-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-object-function-class-declaration-me

Answer (score 2):

**function( a ){ /* … */ }** is an **[anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/function_Operator)** that is directly called with jQuery as parameter. So `a` inside the anonymous function is the same as `jQuery`

### [From jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

> Example: Reverts the $ alias and then
>   creates and executes a function to
>   provide the $ as a jQuery alias inside
>   the functions scope. Inside the
>   function the original $ object is not
>   available. This works well for most
>   plugins that don't rely on any other
>   library.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

read this post also:

[What does (function( $ ){...})( jQuery ); do/mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464635/what-does-function-jquery-do-mean)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's easier to understand the mechanism by thinking of it this way:

```
(function( blah ) {
    blah("hello");
}) ( alert );
```

Note how `blah` becomes a proxy for `alert`. This is just a fancy way of not polluting the global namespace (a lot of libraries use the `$` as a global variable).