# javascript anonymous function

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this JavaScript snippet mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771406/what-does-this-javascript-snippet-mean)

i was wondering why is the double Bracket in the end of the function?

here is simple of the anonymous function :

```
(function(){ ... })();
```

(function(){ ... })**()**;

what those for?

Comment: It's the invocation operator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this JavaScript snippet mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771406/what-does-this-javascript-snippet-mean) or [What (function(){})(); mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192227/what-function-mean) or [What does this “(function(){});”, a function inside brackets, mean in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043647/what-does-this-function-a-function-inside-brackets-mean-in-javascript) or [What is this? (function(){ })()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783723/what-is-this-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declares an anonymous function and invokes it immediately on the same line. Think of it as:

```
foo();
```

where `foo` represents an anonymous function which is declared inline and cannot be referenced by a name.

Comment: thanks , ill mark as answered as soon as i can.

Answer (score 3):

It's a self executing function. Meaning it is excuted immediately.

```
function anon() {
    alert('called');
}
anon(); // alerts at this time

(function () {
    alert('called');
})(); // alerts at this time, calls itself
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample

```
(function(){ ... })();
```

can be rewritten as

```
anonymous = function () { ... };
(anonymous)();
```

or, avoiding the *redundant* first brace pair, as

```
anonymous = function () { ... };
anonymous();
```

at the cost of introducing a name into the (here global) name space.

As pointed out by pst earlier, this construction is used to create a new scope. It is most useful in combination with closures, for example to implement the ubiquitous counter:

```
 var counter = function (initval) {
   var c = initval || 0;
   return function () {
    var r = c;
    c += 1;
    return r;
   };
} (5);

counter () ; // 5
counter () ; // 6
counter () ; // 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function e(){} // function statement, parsed before runtime, can't be anonymous

var e = function (){}; // function expression, parsed at runtime

(function(){}()}); // function expression (evaluated at runtime by the enclosing "()")
```

So, in order to call it, just call the result of the above expression and et voila! You got your self an anonymous self-executing function.

Comment: The function statement and function expression are "parsed" at the same time. The difference is a [real] function statement is "promoted" to the top of the current function (or script outside a function).

Comment: I think you have a typo there

Answer (score 0):

It declares and calls/executes the function.

---

#### Consider `function foo (){ ... }`

If you just had that, it wouldn't do anything.  In order to call `foo` you need the parameter list (albeit null).  So `foo()` would execute.

The same thing applies to an anonymous function.  However, if you have an anonymous function, like `function (){ ... }`, how do you call it?  You have no variable pointing to it.  Without the end `()` it is just a definition, and not a call, so you must add the parens at the end, only you can't do `function (){ ... }()` because of order-of-operation and how JavaScript is interpreted.  Thus you also need to surround the definition in its own parentheses `(function (){...})`.  With the call it would look as you posted `(function (){...})()`.

Note you can also define functions similarly, like:

```
var foo = function (){...};
```

Which essentially is creating an anonymous function and assigning it to a variable.  You can then do `foo()` like you would with any other function.

Answer (score 0):

In the form `expression (...)`, `()` is the function-application operator. It takes in the expression on the left, which *must be a function-object* and invokes it, passing in the supplied parameters, if any. (The other use of `()` is for precedence, which includes `(expression-that-evaluates-to-a-function-object)`.)

The "trick" is to understand this works for *any* expression that evaluates to a *function-object* and that a function-name simply evaluates to the *function-object* it represents. Here is a demonstration:

```
function f1 () { return 1 }
typeof f1     // function
f1()          // 1
var f1b = f1  // f1 evaluates to a function-object which is assigned to f1b
f1b()         // 1
var f2 = function () { return 2 }
typeof f2     // function
(((f2))())    // 2 -- only one of the sets is the application operator
typeof (function () {})       // function
(function () { return 3 })()  // 3 -- any function-object can be applied
```

Happy coding.

---

One reason for using a self-invoking anonymous function is to "create a new scope". New scopes in JavaScript are *only* introduced by new functions.