# could you explain the function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this mean? (function (x,y)){…}){a,b); in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921922/what-does-this-mean-function-x-y-a-b-in-javascript)

```
(function(){
    var foo = 'Hello world';
})();
```

i don't know what's use of it? and what's meaning of it/?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On its own it does nothing except declare a variable that isn't used - it should invoke some other functions to do something useful.

That said, what you have is an *immediately invoked function expression*, i.e. an anonymous function:

```
function() { ... }
```

which is invoked with no parameters:

```
(f....)();
```

The rationale is two fold:

- it allows the function to be defined and called without giving it a name in the global name space
- any variables defined *within* the function are also held within that scope, and don't pollute the global name space.

Comment: Every function expression without a name is an anonymous function.

Answer (score 3):

It's an anonymous function that executes immediately.

The idea is to create a private scope. Often one would return a closure from the anonymous function that retains access to variables created in that scope.

For example

```
var greet = (function () {
    var foo = 'Hello world';
    return function () {
        alert(foo);
    }
}());

greet();
```

Answer (score 0):

This calls an anonymous function immediately.

Have a look here: [What does this “(function(){});”, a function inside brackets, mean in javascript ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043647/what-does-this-function-a-function-inside-brackets-mean-in-javascript/4043744#4043744)

Comment: it's also called a closure sometimes, because all it does is to create a new scope