# Calling a function when page loads

Tags: javascript, function, function-call

[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/dibyaranjan3177/3pNWe/)

This is the code which I have written. The `default` function should be called when the page loads, without clicking any button. It should display some data and then two buttons should be displayed. What modifications do I need in that code?
 I am a beginner so I may have  missed many things please help.

This is my JavaScript part, detailed program is given in the link.

```
function default(){
var i=7;
j=15;
document.write(i+j);
}
```

Comment: *When or under which circumstances* should your `default` function be called? When the page has loaded? After a certain amount of time? Or when some other event occurs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Avoid using Keywords

You cannot use the keyword `default`:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token default
```

You'll need to rename your function.

#### Immediately Invoked Function Expressions

Once you've done that, you can wrap it in parenthesis to execute it immediately:

```
(function dflt(){
  var i = 7, j = 15;
  document.write( i + j );
})();
```

#### Warning: Avoid `document.write`

Note that `document.write` will clear out your document, thus removing the contents of your document. You should instead insert a new text node, or update the contents of an element on the page:

```
(function dflt(){
  var i = 7, j = 15;
  document.body.appendChild( document.createTextNode( i + j ) );
})();
```

You could also add this text node to an element on the page:

```
var tNode = document.createTextNode( i + j );
document.getElementById("foo").appendChild( tNode );
```

This would add the resulting text to any element whose `id` attribute is `foo`:

```
<span id="foo"></span>
```

Comment: When I was writing the code I didn't get any error message rather I got a blank message. May be you can help me telling what should I do for getting error messages rather than getting a blank page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dibyaranjan3177/YLv8G/ What is the problem with this page? When the function test is called the page shows loading icon but there are no item to load!

Comment: @Dibya Why are you using `document.write`? I encouraged you to *avoid* that in my answer above. It will only cause you unnecessary frustration.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Immediately Invoked Function Expression`:

```
(function defaults() { // I edited the function name - "default" can not be used
    var i = 7;         // You can also remove the function name, will work either
    j = 15;            // way. "default" is a reserved word
    document.write(i + j);
})();
```

But it's calling it... you can't run a function without calling it, do you want to execute it with magic?

You should read this:

[What does this "(function(){});", a function inside brackets, mean in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043647/what-does-this-function-a-function-inside-brackets-mean-in-javascript)

---

As @stakx pointed out, you can pass a function reference to functions the execute the function after X time, like `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(defaults, 1000); // execute "defaults" after one second.
```

But it's just like handle it yourself:

```
function foo(aFunction){
    aFunction();
}

foo(defaults);
```

Comment: *"you can't run a function without calling it"* -- agreed, except in scenarios where timers or events are involved.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dibyaranjan3177/3pNWe/1/ I have edited it. The problem is it is not showing the buttons.

Comment: Yep! The self invoking anonymous function :)

Comment: You can remove the name of the function `defaults` as well.

Comment: @stakx in scenarios with events or timers , functions are callbacks so there are indeed ran by them. the statement : " you can't run a function without calling it," still stands in my opinion.

Comment: +1 For pointing the name of this thing: "Immediately Invoked Function Expression"

Comment: @Dibya. See the update, you must call it or pass the reference to a function what will do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to use jQuery (as suggested by @Photon Critical Fatal Error), you could give the [`body` element's `onload` event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp) a try:

```
<body onload="default();">
    ...
</body>
```

Though this might not work as expected. jQuery handles this in a more reliable way, so if you decide to give it a try, look at the [`$(document).ready(…)`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) API function.

Comment: I think he/she don't know the reliability and flexibility of jquery.

Comment: @Photon, agreed, but so what? It's only a suggestion. If the OP doesn't want to use it, there's still the `onload` event.

Comment: but they don't want to call too?

Answer (score 1):

```
function default(){
    var i=7;
    j=15;
    document.write(i+j);
    }
```

default is a reserved word in javascript you cant use it.