# javascript syntax explanation

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this mean? (function (x,y)){…}){a,b); in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921922/what-does-this-mean-function-x-y-a-b-in-javascript)

Please anyone explain and give example about the Javascript below, I can't find any document that explain about this:

```
(function([arg, arg ...]) {

    //javascript code here

})([str, str ...]);
```

I'm asking this question because I see in the Google also Facebook javascript code, most of the them using this syntax.

Comment: Search for javascript closures. http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies

Comment: I doubt that searching on closures will help much. That pattern is called an [immediately invoked function expression](http://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=immediately+invoked+function+expression&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=ZO-XTpzvO9CXiQe60aWsAg) by some. Others have similar names. It can be used to create closures, but it isn't necessary to create a closure nor is it the only way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is, an anonymous function expression is defined (in parentheses) -

```
(function([arg, arg ...]) {

    //javascript code here

})
```

The function is then immediately called using the `()` at the end of the function, just as as you'd call a normal function `var result = someFunction()`. So , for example -

```
(function() {
    alert('Called by "()" at end of function');
})()
```

You can also pass arguments to the anoymous function, via the parentheses -

```
(function(username) {
    alert('Called by "()" at end of function. Hello ' + username + '!');
})('Dave')
```

Comment: +1 - speed is the enemy of accuracy. :-)

Comment: @RobG - Thanks! Not sure I can blame it all on speed though :)

Answer (score 4):

It is anonymous function invocation

the arguments values `str, str` are passed to the function as arguments `arg, arg` and then the javascript code is executed.

it is the same as

```
function foo([arg, arg ...]) {
    //javascript code here
}

foo([str, str, ...]);
```

Comment: +1 for getting it mostly right. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The function in round brackets is called just once with args defined by strs.

The round brackets containing the function are used to limit the scope of the function, i.e. the function cannot be called externally.

The str variables can be global variables (e.g. jQuery) and can be aliased by their corresponding arg (e.g. jQuery -> $) for the sole use of the function.

Generally, this is a good, safe way to write javascript, e.g.

```
(function($) {
   // code
})(jQuery)
```

For the function, the local variable '$' means the global variable 'jQuery'. The means you can have '$' defined to be something else in another script (or function) and that variable will not affect '$' in this function.

Comment: The round brackets containing the function are **not** scope operators. They are there to allow the function to be invoked immediately. If they weren't there, a syntax error would occur.

Comment: Ah, good point - thanks. Although, my point that the function cannot be called externally (since it's anonymous) is still true.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(a, b) {
  var x;
})
```

returns an anonymous function. For technical/historical reasons, anonymous functions must be wrapped in parentheses.

Notably, the names `a`,`b` and `x` are not visible to outside code. In contrast, just writing `var x;` would make `x` accessible and thereby pollute the global namespace. This is the equivalent of private variables in classical object-orientated languages.

We could also write:

```
var func = function(a, b) {var x;};
// or equivalently:
function foo(a, b) {var x;};

func('arg1', 2);
```

but that would again pollute the global namespace by making a function `func` visible for everyone else. Since we don't want to call `func` more than once anyway,

```
(function(a, b) {var x;}) ('arg1', 2);
```

is the perfect way to execute code with variables without making these variables(or *any* variable names) visible to the rest of the world.

Comment: The expression at the top of your post is a function declaration with no name, so it is a syntax error. Given a name to make it syntactically legal, it has no return statement so returns `undefined`, not a function.

Comment: @RobG Thanks. Fixed: Enclosed with parentheses to make it syntactically legal, it indeed returns a function. Note that anonymous functions do not need to be wrapped in parentheses in expressions, only in statements.