# JS function definition : meaning of the last parentheses

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)
>   [What does this mean? (function (x,y)){…}){a,b); in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921922/what-does-this-mean-function-x-y-a-b-in-javascript)

I see sometimes functions defined like these examples :

```
(function() {
    ....     
})();

(function(param) {
    ....     
})(JQuery);

(function(chat, Friend) {
    ....     
})(chat, chat.module("friend");
```

After some web researches, I didn't find any information about the meaning of the last parentheses  information.

Is there someone to explain how to use it? Or simply point a web link explaining the meaning?

Comment: It calls the function with parameters.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Which brackets (parenthesis?) do you mean exactly? Some of these aren't even valid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> meaning of the last brakets

```
(function() {
    ....     
})();
```

The `()` in the end causes the code inside the function to be executed immediately.

```
(function(param) {
    ....     
})(JQuery);
```

The `(JQuery)` in the end causes the code inside the function to be executed immediately, passing `JQuery` as a parameter to it.

```
(function(chat, Friend) {
    ....     
})(chat, chat.module("friend"));
```

The `(chat, chat.module("friend"))` in the end causes the code inside the function to be executed immediately, passing `chat` and `chat.module("friend")` as parameters to it.

Comment: The parentheses are unmatched in code examples #1 and #2. You should fix that for the asker.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Thanks. I didn't notice that, I assume it is a copy-paste error. I fixed them now.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we had:

```
function add1 (x) {
    return x+1;
}
```

Then we might call `add1(5)` to get the value 6.

But with the brackets, rather than calling `add1(5)`, we can replace it with `(function (x) {return x+1;})(5)`.  Basically this creates a function, and applies it to the value 5 immediately, whereas when we call `add1(5)`, we are using a named/defined function.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question: [What is this practice called in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720283/what-is-this-practice-called-in-javascript)

Basically, the function will execute with the parameters you pass it.
In this example, `param` will have the value of `jQuery`:

```
(function(param) {
    ....     
})(JQuery);
```

Comment: It should be an error. The line `})(JQuery);` would be valid, as would `}(JQuery));`, but not `})(JQuery));` unless your starting function statement looks like `((function ($) {` for no reason.