# Understanding javascript functions, scope and closures

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

Can someone explain in detail what this snippet of js does?

```
(function (window) {
    var test = window['test'] = {};
    test.utils = new(function(){ ... })();
})(window);
```

I understand that the function is not globally scoped. I understand that it is creating a variable called test that points to a property in the `window` object that is an empty object. I also understand that `utils` is a property of test.

I don't understand what the purpose of the last part is `(window);` or why the `utils` function is being designated as `new`.

Please explain.

Comment: It's a slightly misguided attempt to make the code in the anonymous (outer) function "safe" from tampering with `window`.  It's misguided because it fails to do that :-)  Instead of passing `window`, the code should pass `this`.

Comment: Neither do I understand. Where did you get that code from, and what does the constructor-invoked function expression contain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? (function (x,y)){...}){a,b); in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921922/what-does-this-mean-function-x-y-a-b-in-javascript)

Comment: `new(function(){ ... })();` is just defining the constructor function and creating an instance in one go. It's the same as `function Foo() {...}` and `new Foo();`. Using an object literal might be easier here, but I cannot tell since I don't know what's the content of the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS function definition : meaning of the last parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103575/js-function-definition-meaning-of-the-last-parentheses)

Comment: thats the second time i see someone using an IEFE, adding properties to a passed (global) `window` Object, the first time it was from some javascript videotutorial, i wonder where this comes from

Comment: this comes from a variation of old knockoutjs code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates a function and calls it immediately, passing in `window`. The function receives an argument called `window` and then creates an empty object on it which is available both as a property on `window` called `test` and as a local variable called `test`. Then it creates an object by calling a function via `new` and assigns that object to `test.utils`.

> I don't understand what the purpose of the last part is (window);...

It doesn't really serve any purpose in the code you've quoted, because the symbol passed into the main (outer) function, `window`, is the same as the name of the argument receiving it. If their names were *different*, then it would serve a purpose, e.g.:

```
(function(wnd) {
})(window);
```

That would make `window` available within the function as `wnd`.

> or why the utils function is being designated as new.

`utils` won't be a function (at least, not unless the code you've replaced with `...` is doing something *really* strange), it will be an object created by *calling* that function.

The whole thing could be rewritten more clearly:

```
(function(window) {

    var test;

    test = {};
    window['test'] = test;

    test.utils = new NiftyThing();

    function NiftyThing() {
    }

})(window);
```

That still does the `window` thing for no reason, but hopefully it makes it clear what the `new(function() { ... })();` bit was doing.

Comment: If you use the `window` variable, it might help minification. That's the only reason I've heard of, yet I think such things should be done by the minifier :-)

Comment: so what would be the difference between `test.utils = new(function(){ ... })();` and `test.utils = function(){ ... };`?

Comment: @bflemi3: In the first, `test.utils` will refer to an object that almost certainly isn't a function. In the second, `test.utils` will refer to a function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is a self-invoked function.

It's invoked itself giving the `window` object as function input argument in order to ensure that, inside the whole function, `window` will have the expected meaning.

```
test.utils = new(function(){ ... })(); <--- This is an object constructor.
```

When the function is called using the `new` operator, it turns into an object constructor.

For example:

```
var conztructor = function() {
   this.name = "Matias";
};

var obj = new conztructor();
alert(obj.name); // <--- This will alert "Matias"!
```

The purpose of `(window);` is creating a new variable and reference holding the JavaScript `Window` object instance, avoiding that other libraries may reuse the `window` (or any other) identifier and your own library may break because of this situation.

This is nice in order to avoid altering global scope identifiers that may be used by other libraries.

### UPDATE

In response to some comments, run this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/wChh6/5/

Comment: Why do you think the `window` variable avoids modifications of the global object?

Comment: ^^^^^--- Its passed as reference, modifications will apply to the global object too, thats why i don't understand the purpose behind this
http://jsbin.com/emaqog/1/edit

Comment: @Bergi Ok, maybe I explained it in the wrong way. I mean that you avoid overwriting the identifier and change what window or anything is designed for.

Comment: @Glutamat Check my update, now I explain it better than before :)

Comment: No, that's wrong. You never will be able to overwrite the global `window` identifier.

Comment: @Bergi thats where i stumbled upon it the first time. MikeBoutin posted a videotutorial link in the javascript [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7510222#7510222) this is the [video](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=159) it should be around 8:30

Comment: @Bergi Try the code in jsFiddle I posted some minutes ago :) See if you can or not.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wChh6/3/ -> that doesn't change anything, you cant set `window` to `null`. And i don't really see any purpose, in setting the copied reference to the `window` Object to null, either

Comment: @Glutamat You didn't understand the sample. It's about showing that reusing the `window` identifier inside the self-executing function, executed before the last alert, doesn't change the window identifier in the global scope. I mean, the VARIABLE holds Window yet!

Comment: @Glutamat: Thanks for the link. The reason for using `window` is explained at 5:20 - and it's trivial :-)

Comment: @Glutamat In response to **And i don't really see any purpose, in setting the copied reference to the window Object to null, either**. Open your mind, man. Setting `window` to null is pointless, but some library could set `window` to whatever, for example a custom object, and if it's not done inside a self-invoked function creating a local var `window`, the rest of the libraries will stop working.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer you're overwriting the reference to the window Object, but that still does not make much sense to me, why would you pass an Object just to destroy its reference, you could've just created a local variable then

Comment: so its just for the convenience of havin the variable called window ?
Oh i just saw Bergis comment, i'll look at 5:20 maybe that makes things clear to me =)

Comment: @Glutamat I'm agree that reusing the `window` identifier isn't a very good practice, but it's for the sake of the sample. Anyway, jQuery both defines `window` and `undefined` as local variables and arguments for the self-invoked function, meaning that they prefer to practice defensive programming and avoid other libraries breaking their own library code. Since `window` or `undefined` aren't keywords, bad coding can break others' one, why not preventing it? It's crazy, but that's the reason!!! :D

Comment: @Glutamat Good programmers won't reuse window reference for storing nothing different than standard window object, but as I said, since other would do, you don't declare a local variable holding `window` for later setting other object, but for just avoiding that other stupid library would change `window` global scope variable and your code would get absolutely wrong.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Noooow i get it =) Thx for that!!!  =) fortunately ES5 specifies `undefined` as not-writable, maybe we're safer in the future (+1)

Comment: @Glutamat W00000000000t!! Finally hahaha Thanks for understanding it ;)

Comment: @Glutamat Yeah, and hopefully sometime JavaScript will be a modern, solid and more predictable language. But if you know the "shit", you can do great things with JS. See the strict mode, for example.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that a new anonymous function is being declared. The last part with `(window)` makes a call to that function, passing `window` as a parameter.

Inside, the call to `test.utils = new(function(){ ... })();` creates a new object (with contents defined by the function passed to `new`) and assigns it to `test.utils`.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a function with last parentetheses, the function is **executed itself** after loading with the parameter given, in your case `window`

```
(function (window) {
    var test = window['test'] = {};
    test.utils = new(function(){ ... })();
})(window);
```

[JS function definition : meaning of the last parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103575/js-function-definition-meaning-of-the-last-parentheses)