# What gets passed where and why between various constructions (const, function, arrow functions, IIFEs) in JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to understand this (radically simplified for purposes of asking this question) bit of code from Wordpress:

```
function MyFooContainer( {
        attr1,
        attr2,
        attr3,
        someVar
} ) {

        // do some stuff
        
        return (
                <>  
                    // some components
                </>
        );
}

const MyFooWrapper = withDispatch( (dispatch, ownProps, registry) => ( {
                // a bunch of code doing stuff, but no returns
        })
)( MyFooContainer );
 
const MyExportedFunction = (props) => {
        const { someVar } = props;
        const myTest = true;

        const Component = myTest
                ? MyFooWrapper
                : SomethingElse;

        return <Component { ...props } />
};

export default MyExportedFunction;
```

The way I understand things (which is probably poorly, as I'm new to both JS and React), someone calls `MyExportedFunction` with a bunch of parameters. One of those gets explicitly pulled out into `someVar`, by name. All of them get passed to `Component` as individual arguments (because of the ellipsis expansion). `Component` because of the way the test is set up, is just `MyFooWrapper`, which takes three arguments in order, so ... the first three `props` had better map to `dispatch`, `ownProps`, and `registry`? After that, I was really confused, but I guess base on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860083/what-means-construction-function) that

```
const myFunction = withDispatch((args) => { })(MyFooContainer);
```

is an IIFE and `MyFooContaner` is passed as an argument to the `withDispatch`? But where did `MyFooContainer` get its arguments?

While we're here, why is `MyFooContainer` explicitly defined as a `function`, whereas the others are assigned as `const`? And last but not least, where does its `return` go? Who is catching that?

Comment: No, it's not an IIFE. It's a function call to the curried function `withDispatch(…)(MyFooContainer)`. Where did you import that one from? See its documentation for what it does and how it should be used. It seems to return a `MyFooWrapper` component, which - when used - will call the `MyFooContainer` with extra props.

Comment: it's from the columns block edit.js. And, I didn't import it, I'm just trying to understand it because I'm trying to write something else and ... this seemed like a good template until I got confused :) (now going to look up "curried function")

Comment: "*why is `MyFooContainer` explicitly defined as a function, whereas the others are assigned as `const`?*" - `MyExportedFunction` could have been a `function` declaration as well, `MyFooContainer` could've been made an arrow function expression as well. No difference. "*Where does its return go? Who is catching that?*" - same as for `MyExportedFunction`: react is rendering the jsx elements you return.