# how does this js function work? Title too small to explain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been digging into jquery to find out how it works and I see it uses a construct i've never seen in JS before. The following code seems to execute when the browser loads, it's almost like a function that invokes itself.  I've searched for docs for this feature but not sure what its called.  Can someone tell me the principle so I can google further info on this?

```
(function test() {
    alert('test');
})();
```

Comment: works pretty good :).. duplicate question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720283/what-is-this-practice-called-in-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872604/is-the-following-javascript-construct-called-a-closure and many other

Comment: I do agree that one would have no idea what to search for in this case.. duplicates are unavoidable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's exactly what it is, a self-invoking anonymous function, the variables inside that scope:

```
(function test() {
  //here
})();
```

Won't be visible outside unless you expose them either.  If you want more detail around uses and practical examples, I'd start with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work).

Comment: thanks.. is this common? Anyway to tell when it's actually being invoked? (i.e.: when the script is read, compiled by the browser or when the page has completed its loading?)

Comment: @Billworth - Yep it's *very* common.  It's being invoked exactly where it occurs in your code, it's not a `document.ready` handler that jQuery uses, that's a different format, like `$(function() { })` or `$(document).ready(function() { });` or `jQuery(function($) { });`.

Comment: It's true that these are commonly called "self-invoking" or "self-executing", but they don't *really* invoke themselves. Something like, "immediately invoked and discarded anonymous function" would be more accurate, but I don't think it'll catch on :-)

Comment: @Pointy I think it will eventually. http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 3):

<strike>It is a self-executing function.</strike>

It is a immediately invoked function expression.

It is used to create a local scope. If you have a code-snippet that requires lots of new variables, and you only need to run that code once, then it is a good idea to encapsulate the snippet with this function (so that the variables form the snippet don't pollute the global namespace).

```
(function() {
    // all variables and functions declared here are not visible
    // outside of this function
})();
```

However, in your code, the function is not anonymous - you called it "test", so it is a named function expression. It is probably best to not define names for function expressions (because there are bugs in Internet Explorer related to this issue:
http://github.com/kangax/nfe