# hoisting of variables in closure

Tags: javascript

In javascript variable declaration is hoisted in the top.

But

```
var v;
v=1;                 ----------------------------
var getValue=(function(v){
return function(){return v;};
})(v);
v=2;              -----------------------------VVV

                                  both are outside function

but results getValue();//1
```

why this time `v=2` is not hoisted at top?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing `1` not `2` is not about hoisting, but the [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572) that you create around `getValue` with that [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720283/what-is-this-practice-called-in-javascript) -  where a local `v` variable with the value `1` shadows the global `v` variable.

```
var v; // hoisted declaration - global variable "v"
v=1; // "1" is assigned to the global
var getValue=(function(v) { // a function with a local "v" variable (parameter)
    return function(){return v;}; // access the local "v" variable
})(v); // passing the value of the global variable - "1" as the time of the call
v=2; // "2" is assigned to the global variable
getValue(); // the local variable still has the value: 1
```

If you omit that parameter, your `getValue` will return the global variable - as the time of the call to it:

```
var v; // hoisted declaration
// v=1; // irrelevant
var getValue = // (function() { can be omitted
    function() { return v; } // access the global variable
// })() 
v = 2; // assign the variable
getValue() // and access it from the closure: 2
```